# IPV6 Unique-local address and site local address

Tags: ipv6

Is there any difference between unique-local address and site-local addresses ? or both are meant to be same?

Comment: PS: this question is actually off-topic here and should probably be moved to SuperUser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Site local addresses have been deprecated. Unique local addresses are designed to be used instead.

Because site local addresses would cause conflicts when setting up VPNs between networks and when merging networks they were deprecated. Unique local addresses make sure that each network uses different addresses so that linking and merging won't be a problem.

Comment: Unfortunately many administrators ignore section 3.2 of RFC 4193 and configure unique local addresses in a way which will end up conflicting anyway.

Comment: If you're an idiot when configuring your network then you deserve it when it breaks ;)

Comment: @SanderSteffann Sure, the administrators deserve it. But they may affect users who have no influence on the administrators' misguided decisions. But at least when it breaks the users have two different administrators they can scream at instead of only one.